# FB Javascript SDK - redirect uri

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

hi i'm trying to do click on a link and trigger facebook post to wall dialog (i've user authorize) and if user post to wall something or close the dialog box i want to redirect page to url that i generated. In chrome, yandex browser its okay but in firefox its doing good but when redirects new page, in 2 secs it returns to beginning. This problem about redirect_uri parameter ? How can i solve this? I want to go redirected page and stop there. Here's my codes;

```
$("a#generate-code").click(function() {
            var road_to = $(this).attr("link_url");

            if (road_to != "javascript:;") {
                FB.ui({
                    method: 'feed',
                    name: 'App Name',
                    link: 'http://apps.facebook.com/app_link',
                    picture: 'http://blah.com/sunderex.jpg',
                    caption: 'App Caption',
                    description: 'App Desc.',
                    redirect_uri : ""
                },
                function(response) {
                    if (response && response.post_id) {
                        location.href = road_to;
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        location.href = road_to;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: _“but in firefox its doing good but when redirects new page, in 2 secs it returns to beginning”_ – no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: i mean in firefox im doing same actions. Like im clicking link and its triggers feed dialog i'm sharing something or close dialog it goes to url with location.href = road_to; but in few seconds page redirects to main page.

Comment: it seems we need second page source 
can you give me your website or app url ?
& `redirect_uri : ""` is not needed :)